# How do/can I generate a PKCS#12 file using python and the cryptography module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pkcs#12, python-cryptography

How do/can I generate a PKCS#12 file using python and the [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) module?

It's pretty easy using said module to generate the contents of .pem file for a private key:

```
keyPEMBytes = privateKey.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption())
```

Also easy to generate the contents of a .cer/.pem file for an associated cert:

```
certBytes = certificate.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM)
```

But I need them (and their chain) balled up on a single .p12 (PKCS12 file). Said module documents [how to parse/consume PKCS12 formats](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/?highlight=PKCS12#pkcs12), but nothing (that I can find) about how one can generate them.

My understanding of PKI stuff is hit and miss though, so maybe I'm just not searching the right keyword in the documentation?

I *can* create the .p12 file at the command line on Linux using

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out myIdentity.p12 -inkey myPrivKey.pem -in myCert.crt -certfile myCertChain.crt
```

So I could just wrap calls like this with subprocess/cmd and mess with tempfiles/pipes. I was hoping to keep it all in memory/python though.

Is there a different python TLS library that I should be considering, that *can* do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you noted, `cryptography` can parse PKCS12 (at least the subset used by 99.99% of people) with [load_key_and_certificates](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12.load_key_and_certificates), but serialization to PKCS12 is not currently supported.

I'm one of the core developers for the project and in general `cryptography`'s feature set is driven by users filing issues that explain their use case and need for a particular feature. I'd recommend writing something up on the tracker for discussion. It sounds like your needs would be covered by a simple API looking roughly like:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12 import generate_pkcs12

pem_pkcs12 = generate_pkcs12(
    BestAvailableEncryption(b"somepassword"), 
    key, 
    [cert1, cert2]
)
```

Update: this feature is implemented in pyca/cryptography 3.0:

https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization.html?highlight=pkcs12#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12.serialize_key_and_certificates

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'generate_pkcs12' from 'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12'

Comment: @paul-kehrer Maybe you should update your answer. See also [https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/7359](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/7359),

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the code [here](https://www.example-code.com/python/pfx_create_from_pem_files.asp) might be useful? It's not the cryptography module -- it's chilkat, but it does the job.

```
import sys
import chilkat

#  First load our certificate into a certificate object,
#  and then get it as a cert chain object.
cert = chilkat.CkCert()

success = cert.LoadFromFile("qa_data/rsaes-oaep/cert.pem")
if (success != True):
    print(cert.lastErrorText())
    sys.exit()

#  This is the certificate PEM that we loaded:

#  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#  MIIDozCCAougAwIBAgIJAMRwugDmvniwMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMGgxCzAJBgNV
#  BAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQIDAJJTDEQMA4GA1UEBwwHV2hlYXRvbjEhMB8GA1UECgwY
#  SW50ZXJuZXQgV2lkZ2l0cyBQdHkgTHRkMRcwFQYDVQQDDA5DaGlsa2F0V2lkZ2V0
#  czAeFw0xNzA0MTgxMzQxNDVaFw0yMjA0MTcxMzQxNDVaMGgxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
#  MQswCQYDVQQIDAJJTDEQMA4GA1UEBwwHV2hlYXRvbjEhMB8GA1UECgwYSW50ZXJu
#  ZXQgV2lkZ2l0cyBQdHkgTHRkMRcwFQYDVQQDDA5DaGlsa2F0V2lkZ2V0czCCASIw
#  DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMXhMR7TNHSaHgrEGvAmHNqw/8xV
#  5TcngVO//yHBniDHas5b2zm0AkhY5EW9dn0wTWHivoRZC2soH7/bxRi4uYUaxgve
#  YLXw6DO2MHSpuTvhSG3+AjsBDa9kXegn9XT1MdPHk9PrHR0sKXGuimkLf4r+Q1oM
#  iGlhbUyRATwVlmo6AndgniDnj2RFBYV8E8SQ+7SnLPJdXZRDbLNVY/DY6D9stRAY
#  rHuz/WBlVW7TQVuWwe7Cd9bfFqjqzLwLksKevWvHGteYDGeiCi+uvMMNfp/Br79Y
#  zJYF/YpTJYE0POBiMwth1FUIYKpZf/O2eUd6RW9h6hocC5QWU9LAq+7kKFMCAwEA
#  AaNQME4wHQYDVR0OBBYEFKBCsni1BfOyH3dSoY8yL4mDeNbpMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaA
#  FKBCsni1BfOyH3dSoY8yL4mDeNbpMAwGA1UdEwQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
#  BQADggEBAF2iV69ma5XegVWpxbc0gui63RE8NjW2dBW0fa4a4fwNH2f8oetZEjw4
#  kscx7p4ESxyPtDUkLNplAth+D8NNh9IQDWIld+FZrJsis4tkpVcpMsbmB2CW8fL2
#  IVnVznAN+/PMYEAkeSOnovUGlREHZZu4b9rMVm89+aoCQ9z+byjW9kLKHyvLnUai
#  uEHp+0EVFP91CRSIcTCXsW1c5yZ8k5bqL0HlauuOO4TA3IegyYM9xBubmcxg8cRO
#  2F1k+Ge1lu3e+WY+lihaO0p762dF6g/SUMMrFneCPdIhvt4u7Esc9FDxE3xZEq3x
#  cS5sHTxtTM0LVBi378/x5m1hln5hSJU=
#  -----END CERTIFICATE-----

#  Get it as a certificate chain.
# certChain is a CkCertChain
certChain = cert.GetCertChain()
if (cert.get_LastMethodSuccess() != True):
    print(cert.lastErrorText())
    sys.exit()

#  Next, load the corresponding private key from a PEM.
privKey = chilkat.CkPrivateKey()
success = privKey.LoadPemFile("qa_data/rsaes-oaep/privateKey.pem")
if (success != True):
    print(privKey.lastErrorText())

    sys.exit()

#  This is the private key PEM:

#  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
#  MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAxeExHtM0dJoeCsQa8CYc2rD/zFXlNyeBU7//IcGeIMdqzlvb
#  ObQCSFjkRb12fTBNYeK+hFkLaygfv9vFGLi5hRrGC95gtfDoM7YwdKm5O+FIbf4C
#  OwENr2Rd6Cf1dPUx08eT0+sdHSwpca6KaQt/iv5DWgyIaWFtTJEBPBWWajoCd2Ce
#  IOePZEUFhXwTxJD7tKcs8l1dlENss1Vj8NjoP2y1EBise7P9YGVVbtNBW5bB7sJ3
#  1t8WqOrMvAuSwp69a8ca15gMZ6IKL668ww1+n8Gvv1jMlgX9ilMlgTQ84GIzC2HU
#  VQhgqll/87Z5R3pFb2HqGhwLlBZT0sCr7uQoUwIDAQABAoIBAGCP5LWDIWzpLFHa
#  or6gCqKZjyo6nFFO4Ohqn+jsH+slBTTQVGmTMy302uhBbYnnwUtMJ+ZTwaO3/85T
#  Q5otwrJ2f0CZcx42AkoB1SGJFVBoPj0WoCYE/JWjZ8P7g+dgI8GR+cyHRjzPKSZF
#  o1thdgrwyxMtXH/4QCsF89FLQ4xwCJUkj+w0KBkX8isWcBJnKip81MK8rxhgMJ6v
#  5+DBVvlvm4BRz0hva7HB3TaZgo9ZWZdoSJQ/l33yfIL8H0EJjC6uJ/Bn77JtDzcv
#  1oUF02Ebu8/Re7RpUqdTIb1GamrOCjuZN66SrCOsh9rRzueU3UTLzjb9FDv8FQDA
#  5Dm59KECgYEA6zJ2LaiUywth80rAC34jEF85aC3vyKK0MxYELLB9Nw6MNFD1PZly
#  YkOcI2kxVV+1KqtRYFlfEpCL4flqVnqjVj5jTCCOXqO6RjnPLoupf0yLpj60raO6
#  Ouw5EDGjfUDBQtkCQNOx0nZLftVy30Ck/V2gVw9sEgWQV0YRavuymKMCgYEA12HB
#  eHHSo/dK7keiIK7RRQu2ibALXWXsGq9lUbnQAunKRCa3qQtc8OwGRZsdj9u8HwCB
#  zDu5QIbaQCa1SyDz1CsOysOfTYNhh1SZ4GLiu7/b0v5ktgdtosT9niowo08Y4ZU+
#  lA8p2eriylznacNOkA8O1g8m1etHqV+cVKUMvJECgYEApoeVO6DosZd+pCfiMIEA
#  TMBPwl78L6BcXOuSyx2vmwMW7JgB/LqgTck3Ta9Wue9JNEwXE1RUR63HDZpu24p8
#  Cj2kSyumAoaFBuI5uugyfCrzmiM+BNAvtTa69Kdg7feinzVOLh52AuG1dLmnW0HH
#  UIoxVFNcHqqH1/OJs6lBfGcCgYEAkQXhn5gEnSMF8SuKnzcW8cbRQiSnglv+fnlb
#  X4wd49hHuVvYjpp4GkDSeEvZu+PY54cP3tTYB/rFOizWJaAqjdHwQ9c0jJzKLrVo
#  Zw4uXPzypz9j0K1vxQmfO8Bsv4mi10IGwOr04yalTlz/9NbtL1L0Sm4pWCD0P7eB
#  K/12dgECgYBXNV5NcLpZhpjo8q05xAiFuwC2e29qYyVwcFVhYdYguutRKImZtjSE
#  dndNAxa7EDL9NRc5SjX4NHAZoImADRSbgc2rIq2ePY8WORaR+iKsVx7PJGHSiXTL
#  30X9E3com8ctyTsZTnlJ4Dm7SefkN0NKzqwjxXxZLaUteWBPUt+YAg==
#  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

#  Create a PFX object instance, and add the private key + cert chain.
pfx = chilkat.CkPfx()
success = pfx.AddPrivateKey(privKey,certChain)
if (success != True):
    print(pfx.lastErrorText())

    sys.exit()

#  Finally, write the PFX w/ a password.
success = pfx.ToFile("pfxPassword","qa_output/sample.pfx")
if (success != True):
    print(pfx.lastErrorText())
    sys.exit()

print("Success.")
```

Answer (score 1):

#This assumes you have server.key and server.pem already created

```
import sys
import os
from OpenSSL import crypto

try:
  PFX_Passcode = os.environ['PFX_Passcode']
except KeyError:
  sys.exit('One or more required environment variables not set, required: PFX_Passcode')

with open('server.key', "r") as f:
  privkeydata = f.read()
with open('server.pem', 'r') as f:
  certdata = f.read()
cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, certdata)
privkey = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, privkeydata)
p12 = crypto.PKCS12()
p12.set_privatekey(privkey)
p12.set_certificate(cert)
p12data = p12.export(PFX_Passcode)
with open('server.pfx', 'wb') as pfxfile:
  pfxfile.write(p12data)
```

Comment: great concise answer that uses a commonly used openSSL library, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution doesn't work anymore. This use the python module `cryptography` and generate a p12 file:

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import pkcs12, PrivateFormat

common_name = "John Doe"
password = "secret"

private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
     public_exponent=65537,
     key_size=4096,
)

cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate("myCert.crt")

encryption = (
     PrivateFormat.PKCS12.encryption_builder().
     kdf_rounds(50000).
     key_cert_algorithm(pkcs12.PBES.PBESv1SHA1And3KeyTripleDESCBC).
     hmac_hash(hashes.SHA1()).build(f"{password}".encode())
)

p12 = pkcs12.serialize_key_and_certificates(
    f"{common_name}".encode(), private_key, cert, None, encryption
)


with open(f"{common_name}.p12", "wb") as p12_file:
    p12_file.write(p12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite annoying that there isn't a clear example documented in the cryptography module.  Here's the magic incantation to convert pem files (cert + key) into a p12 file protected by a password.

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import BestAvailableEncryption, load_pem_private_key, pkcs12

hostname = "host.domain.com"
crt_file = "cert.pem"
key_file = "privkey.pem"
p12_file = 'host.p12'
password = "password"
with open(crt_file, mode='rb') as file:
  crt = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(file.read())
with open(key_file, mode='rb') as file:
  key = load_pem_private_key(file.read(), None)
with open(p12_file, 'wb') as file:
  file.write(
      pkcs12.serialize_key_and_certificates(
          hostname.encode(), key, crt, None,
          BestAvailableEncryption(password.encode())))
```